# Живые плитки в меню пуск Windows 10 не обновляются картинки

Tags: windows-10, tile

Я создал живую плитку в меню пуск, используя документацию  `Microsoft`, которая получает информацию из сайта т.е при каждом обновлении получаем последние 5 новостей. Основная проблема в том, что при обновлении (установил каждые 30 минут) обновляется только название на плитке, а вот изображения остаются те же. Я проверил на различных компьютерах, тот же результат, в течение нескольких часов обновляется только название плитки... Скажите пожалуйста, как исправить данный баг ?
Заметил ещё одну странность, если один раз добавить ссылку в меню пуск, через `EDGE` , далее удалить её из меню ( `Unpin from start`) то второй раз уже невозможно добавить данную ссылку в меню пуск, т.е уже при добавлении показывает только фиксированную иконку (которую прописал в `XML`) без анимации и показа информации... насколько мне понятно тут идёт кеширование, если - да, как можно удалить "старый кеш" ? 
И ещё один дополнительный вопрос ответа на который не нашёл в документации, можно ли к каждой плитке добавить отдельную ссылку на сайт?, т.е я подключаю 5 `XML` файлов через `polling-uri` , в плитке показываются по очереди новости, но при нажатии, пользователя всегда перекидывает на страницу которую он добавил ( `Pin to taskbar` ), есть ли возможность добавить отдельную ссылку для каждого `XML` файла, чтобы пользователь, при нажатии на плитку, смог попасть именно на страницу данной новости ? 
Буду рад любой помощи!

> UPD

```
<meta name="application-name" content="Title" />
<meta name="application-TileColor" content=" #FFFFFF" />
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="https://site.ru/browserconfig.xml" />

<meta name="msapplication-notification" content="frequency=30;polling-uri=https://www.site.ru/images/app/msapplication/part1.xml;polling-uri2=https://www.site.ru/images/app/msapplication/part2.xml;polling-uri3=https://www.site.ru/images/app/msapplication/part3.xml;polling-uri4=https://www.site.ru/images/app/msapplication/part4.xml;polling-uri5=https://www.site.ru/images/app/msapplication/part5.xml;cycle=1"/>
```

Добавляю как описанно в документации [тык](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
На сайте сделал динамическую генерацию 5 XML файлов и в header сайта установил meta polling-uri указав путь к данным файлам.

Comment: 1. Как добавляли? У вас UWP-приложение или что? 2. Нет.

Comment: @Андрей добавил пример кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из того что с решением данной проблемы не помогли даже разработчики с  `msdn.microsoft.com`, пришлось самому найти причину проблемы с обновлением картинок в Живых плитках Windows.Причина банальна, при обновлении посредством `XML` происходит кеширование картинок на стороне `Windows`, т.е если названия изображений не меняются, то `Windows` просто не скачивает новые изображения для плиток. Единственная панацея для этого - всегда динамически менять (генерировать) новые имена для изображений и только после этого вписывать в `XML`. Возможно данный совет будет полезен для многих и поможет сэкономить кучу времени :)